# Easy way to integrate branches into trunk

Tags: svn, git, tortoisesvn

I'm running Subversion version 1.4.3 (r23084) + tortoise, and my problem is integrating an branch into trunk. Tortoise's merge didnt work, i got to do this from console.

Its always a hard work to do because of many issues, so i've been thinking about some changes. 
Will a subversion update (its on 1.6 now) resolve my problem? 
Or its better to change everything and start all over again with GIT ?

tnx!

Comment: Define "merge didn't work."  What was wrong?

Comment: In general, if the question is "will Git merge more gracefully than Subversion", the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge tracking was added to svn in 1.5, so yes upgrading will likely solve some of your merging issues.

If your only complaint about svn is its merging, you should upgrade before doing something as drastic as switching to git.

That said, git is much better than svn for lots of reasons, and I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this is always rather hard with SVN. Not impossible, but a lot of legwork.

You may try to use [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn); maybe it will make merges easier while saving you the trouble to change the rest of the workflow.

Comment: You can use git with git-svn to merge svn branches, but you have to be careful. It will not update svn:merge-info (in svn 1.5+), and svn does not understand git merge commits.